# MongoDB : best way to storing key value data

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have to migrate from MySQL to MongoDB , and i beginner in MongoDB, what is the best way to storing below data in MongoDB ?

- should i create a document for each row?
- should i save all row in a one document?

[image]

Which one is valid way in MongoDB?

```
{
  "_id"   : ObjectId("5659d56fef6c702fbc45cc1b")
  "key"   : "setting_update_id"
  "value" : "1"
  "extra" :
  [
    //some data
  ]
}
```

OR

```
{
  "_id"               : ObjectId("5659d56fef6c702fbc45cc1b")
  "setting_update_id" : "1"
  "extra" :
  [
    //some data
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali,

As a beginner you would want to read the docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/). Each `collection` can be thought of roughly as a `table` in a relational database. And each `document` can be thought of as a row in the database. So each `column` of your `table` would be the `keys` of your document.

I would design it closer to the first one.

```
{
  "_id"   : ObjectId("5659d56fef6c702fbc45cc1b")
  "key"   : "setting_update_id"
  "value" : "1"
  "params" :
  {
     "extra" : "hello",
     "foo" : "bar"
   }
}
```